# Definition of the relative de-Rham cohomology and its generalization

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $N$ be its smooth submanifold. We say that two closed forms $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2 \in \Lambda^k(M)$ are equivalent if their difference is an exact form from $\Lambda^k(M)$, the set of classes of equivalence is called the $k$-th de-Rham cohomology group $H^k(M)$. Now to define the relative cohomology group $H^k(M,N)$ we say that two closed forms $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ from $\Lambda^k(M)$ are equivalent if their difference is an exact form from $\Lambda^k(M)$ with support in $M \setminus N$. Is it correct? If it is correct is it possible to define something like relative cohomology in the following case: let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2 \in \Lambda^k(M)$ be closed forms such that their difference is exact $(=d\eta)$ and in a fixed coordinate system the coefficients of $d\eta$ near a fixed point $p \in M$ have the fixed decrease rate $o(|x|^{-\sigma})$, $\sigma >0$?

Comment: Did you try to google "relative de Rham complex"? Try it, you will get plenty if references; the answer to your 1st question is yes.

Comment: @studiosus thank you. Yes, I tried. All the links are about the case when $N$ is a submanifold of $M$, I think it's always the usual relative cohomology as in my definition

Comment: You do not really need N to be a submanifold, just a closed subset. A word of caution: Relative de Rham complex is defined via forms supported away from N.

Comment: @studiosus hm, if $N$ is a submanifold and $i \colon N \to M$ is the inclusion map then the exact form $d\eta$ in the definition must satisfy $i^* d\eta = 0$. But what we require in the case of $N$ a subset? We require the closure of all points where coefficients of $d\eta$ are not null to not intersect $N$?